# Как отменить событие touchstart, если произошел скроллинг

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В js вот такая конструкция обрабатывает тапы по баннеру:

```
$('#slider').on('touchstart', '.tp-caption > a', function(){
    self.location = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Проблема в том, что при этом нет разницы хочет ли пользователь тапнуть на баннер или просто зацепил его, чтобы проскроллить страницу. В любом случае при касании баннера происходит переход по ссылке. Как сделать так, чтобы переход происходил только по тапу без скроллинга? Я пробовал заменить событие touchstart на обычный click, но он почему-то не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос изменив событие на touchend и добавив перед ним проверку на touchmove (записывается в переменную)

```
//Переменная, в которую записывается, было ли перемещение
var scrl = false; 

//Если было совершено событие touchmove, меняем значение переменной на true
$('#slider').on('touchmove', '.tp-caption > a', function(){
    scrl = true;
});

//Во время выполнения touchend проверяем было ли перемещение, если было - обнуляем 
//значение переменной, а если не было - переходим по ссылке
$('#slider').on('touchend', '.tp-caption > a', function(){
    if (scrl != true){
        self.location = $(this).attr('href');
    }else{
        scrl = false;
    }
});
```